# Split an XML to send it to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a question about splitting a XML input parameter and sending it to another stored procedure (SQL Server).

I have a master stored procedure which has in input a XML (see below). 
I would like this stored procedure to split the XML by RDHistorique.
Then send every RDHistorique to a child stored procedure.

```
<ArrayOfRDHistorique>
  <RDHistorique>
    <Id>1955</Id>
    <sect_code>08</sect_code> 
    <arch_islast>0</arch_islast>  
    <ListeEtapes>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>00</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2009-12-31</Date>
            <Commentaire />
            <Id>1955</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>02</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2009-12-31</Date>
            <Commentaire />
            <Id>1955</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>03</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2010-06-23</Date>
            <Commentaire>Silly comment</Commentaire>
            <Id>1955</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>04</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2010-06-23</Date>
            <Commentaire>Silly comment</Commentaire>
            <Id>1955</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>05</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2010-06-23</Date>
            <Commentaire />
            <Id>1955</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
    </ListeEtapes>
  </RDHistorique>
    <RDHistorique>
    <Id>1999</Id>
    <sect_code>08</sect_code> 
    <arch_islast>0</arch_islast> 
    <ListeEtapes>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>00</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2010-12-31</Date>
            <Commentaire />
            <Id>1999</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>02</Statut>
            <Nom>John DOE</Nom>
            <Date>2010-12-31</Date>
            <Commentaire />
            <Id>1999</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>03</Statut>
            <Nom>NULL</Nom>
            <Date>2011-06-29</Date>
            <Id>1999</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>06</Statut>
            <Nom>NULL</Nom>
            <Commentaire>Silly comment</Commentaire>
            <Id>1999</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
        <EtapeWorkflowArchive>
            <Statut>11</Statut>
            <Nom>NULL</Nom>
            <Commentaire>NULL</Commentaire>
            <Id>1999</Id>
        </EtapeWorkflowArchive>
    </ListeEtapes>
  </RDHistorique>
</ArrayOfRDHistorique>
```

I know I can do what I want using cursors, but I would like to do it using Select.
I can already select the nodes I want like this:

```
SELECT 
    b.value('(./Statut/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Statut,
    b.value('(./Nom/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Nom,
    b.value('(./Commentaire/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Commentaire


FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfRDHistorique/RDHistorique/ListeEtapes/*') as a(b)
```

My question is then: Can I call a stored procedure for every node in a XML File?

Comment: *"Can I call a stored procedure for every node in a XML File?"* You would (unfortunately) need to use a `CURSOR` to achieve something like that. Iterative tasks are generally quite slow in SQL, so this may well be an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1):

I you really need iterative approach (procedure is already written, you do some NON-SQL jobs), [CURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/cursors-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the option:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcessStatut(@statut varchar(50), @nom varchar(50),@commentaire varchar(50)) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @statut Statut, @nom Nom, @commentaire Commentaire, 'Hello world!' Hello
END
```

Then:

```
DECLARE @statut varchar(50), @nom varchar(50),@commentaire varchar(50);
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    b.value('(./Statut/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Statut,
    b.value('(./Nom/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Nom,
    b.value('(./Commentaire/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Commentaire
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfRDHistorique/RDHistorique/ListeEtapes/*') as a(b)

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @statut, @nom, @commentaire
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    EXEC ProcessStatut @statut, @nom, @commentaire
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @statut, @nom, @commentaire
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Each row will be processed separately.

---

Edit 1:
If you need to pass table, you can declare TABLE type:

```
CREATE TYPE StatutList AS TABLE (
    Statut varchar(50),
    Nom varchar(50),
    Commentaire varchar(50)
)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcessStatutList(@statutList StatutList READONLY) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *, 'I was here!' Hello FROM @statutList
END
GO
```

And then, use this to pass all items at once:

```
DECLARE @statutList StatutList;
INSERT @statutList
SELECT 
    b.value('(./Statut/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Statut,
    b.value('(./Nom/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Nom,
    b.value('(./Commentaire/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as Commentaire
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfRDHistorique/RDHistorique/ListeEtapes/*') as a(b)

EXEC ProcessStatutList @statutList;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
Would it be possible to send <ListeEtapes> as parameter of the ProcessStatut procedure? 
We tried to do it with "b.value" but it didn't seem to work.